# Как правильно вывести чарт с данными из store?

Tags: extjs, диаграммы

У меня есть Chart, который находится в Panel, Search gridPanel и Controller, который проверяет клик на Search raw элементах. Контроллер который я использую собирает информацию по клику с gridPanel raw и записывает их в параметры Proxy Stor'а (код компании) с последующим вызовом внешнего апи. После клика по raw информация подгружается, я проверял ответ store.load(), нужные данные приходят, но подгрузить чарт и вывести данные на нем не получается. Вот сноски кода:
Controller:

```
this.control({
        'Search': {  //gridPanel компонент, который мы проверяем
            selectionchange: this.SearchSelectionChange
        }
    });
},

SearchSelectionChange: function(arg, records) {

    if (records.length > 0) {

        var me = this;
        var record = records[0];
        me.code = record.data.dataset_code; //getting code from raw

            me.store = Ext.create('Project.store.MarketDataStore'); //подгружаем store
            me.store.getProxy().extraParams = {
                code: me.code  //меняем свойство Proxy нашего store. code берется с raw Search gridPanel'a
            };
            me.store.load(function(records, success, options){ 
            console.log(records); // выводит пришедшие данные(данные верны) 
                if(records == null){Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Error');} 
            });

        var chart = Ext.create('Project.view.Chart'); //Теперь я так понимаю должен прогрузиться Chart?
        chart.redraw(); //И даже после этого чарт не прогружается
}
```

Panel:
(Chart автоматически рендерится при объявлении )

```
Ext.define('Project.view.Panel', {
      extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
      requires: 'Project.view.Chart',
      alias: 'widget.ChartPanel',
      autoShow: true,
      layout: 'fit',
      items: [{
        xtype: 'ProjectChart'
      }]
});
```

и кусочек Chart component:(series и axes верны, проверял на хардкоженых данных)

```
Ext.define('Project.view.Chart', {
requires:    ['Ext.chart.axis.Category','Ext.chart.axis.Numeric','Ext.chart.series.Line','Ext.util.Point', 'Project.store.MarketDataStore'],
extend: 'Ext.chart.Chart',
alias: 'widget.ProjectChart',
  store: 'MarketDataStore',
storeId: 'сhart',
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
animate: true,
autoShow: true,
```

Попробовал внести store,model, Chart в один файл и Chart смог прогрузиться после store.load();. Главный вопрос: Как правильно загружать, перезагружать, перерисовывать Chart с корректными данными Store?

Если где-то не состыковываются название классов и т.д - это точно не проблема, просто поправил в собственных интересах и возможно где-то пропала целостность. Вопрос в том как правильно заставить Chart принимать данные с последующей прогрузкой/перегрузкой на экран
Спасибо.

Comment: this site [ru.so] for question and answers on russian language. please translate your question on russian language or ask question on [so]